# SSJS Platform.Response.Redirect throws error in Try Catch Statement

Tags: javascript, .net, salesforce, ssjs, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I suspect threadabortexception issue of .NET but I couldn't fix it with possible options.

In short Redirect function throws an errors and goes to the catch, no matter to set the second parameter true or false).

The code below is just an example (but I faced this a couple of times before in real-time projects).

```
...

       try {

            var TSD = TriggeredSend.Init("DE_Name");
            var Status = TSD.Send(data.subscriber, data.attributes);

            if (Status != "OK") {
                Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@error_page"));
            } else {
                Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@thanks_page"));  //<<<-- This redirect throw error
            }
        } catch (err) {
            Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@error_page")); // <---- here it comes
        }
...
```

Resources might helps:
1# https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response-end-response-redir

2# https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformClientBrowserRedirect.htm?search_text=Redirect

Any workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but I think it would be good to share findings.

There is no logical explanation to me why this is happen but the Redirect always throws an error and if it is used in a try block, the catch part will be executed.

Here is a simple workaround:

```
...

   try {

        var TSD = TriggeredSend.Init("DE_Name");
        var Status = TSD.Send(data.subscriber, data.attributes);

        try { 
            if (Status != "OK") {
                Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@error_page"));
            } else {
                Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@thanks_page"));  //<<<-- This redirect throw error
            }
        } catch(e) {}

    } catch (err) {
        Platform.Response.Redirect(Variable.GetValue("@error_page")); // <---- here it comes
    }
...
```